# Increase in argument of a smooth function (Gamelin V.III. section 2 exercise 8)

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is question 8 in chapter 8.2 of Gamelin.

Let $D$ be a domain in the complex plane and $f(z)$ a smooth complex valued function on $D$. Suppose that for any $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ and any circle $\partial D(z_0,\varepsilon)\subset D$ such that $f(z)+az+b\neq 0$ for all $z\in \partial D(z_0,\varepsilon)$, the increase in argument around such a circle is non-negative. That is,
\begin{equation}
\oint_{\partial D(z_0,\varepsilon)} d\,\text{arg} (f(z)+az+b)\geq 0.
\end{equation}
We can then supposedly prove that $f(z)$ is analytic.

The hint is given to expand $f(z)$ as a taylor series and to notice that if $A=\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \overline{z}}(z_0)\neq 0$, then the increase in argument of $A(\overline{z}-\overline{z_0})+o(\lvert z-z_0\rvert)$ around $\lvert z-z_0\rvert =\varepsilon$ is strictly negative. I tried to mess around with this hint, and I got that clearly the increase in argument for the first term is $-2\pi$, but how do I do anything with the little o term? I think I'm still not clear on what this notation is actually saying. This is in the chapter on Rouche's Theorem, so maybe I can use that, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: by definition, the $o$ term goes to zero with $\epsilon$ so it is negligible and the $-2\pi$ dominates; in particular choosing $a,b$ to cancel the $(df/dz) (z-z_0)$ term, you get the required contradiction to $A \ne 0$

Comment: right it goes to zero, but why does its change in argument go to zero also? Maybe this is a stupid question. It seems like it could circle the origin any number of times.

Comment: added it as an answer as it is a bit long for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A(\overline{z}-\overline{z_0})+o(\lvert z-z_0\rvert)=A(\overline{z}-\overline{z_0})(1+o(1))$ so the increase in the argument of $A(\overline{z}-\overline{z_0})+o(\lvert z-z_0\rvert)$ is the same as the increase in the argument of $A(\overline{z}-\overline{z_0})$

(for example by taking a simple homotopy $A(\overline{z}-\overline{z_0})(1+o(1)t)$ which cannot go through zero for any $0 \le t \le 1$ because $1+o(1)t \ne 0, 0 \le t \le 1$)

Comment: I see, so the $o(\lvert z-z_0\rvert)$ term is essentially not large enough to get us back to the origin, thus it cant change the increase in argument? That's the same idea as in Rouche's Theorem right?

Comment: yes - note that usually Rouche theorem is stated for analytic functions, but one can state a variant for continuous functions and the above is of this type - note that for continuous functions with the right conditions (isolated zeroes etc) one can still have negative order zeroes like in your case $\overline{z}-\overline{z_0}$, so the analog of Rouche is trickier as the change in argument measures the total number of zeroes with both plus/minus multiplicities; for analytic functions, multiplicities of zeroes are positive, so we get the usual exact form of Rouche